# File containing directory structure

Tags: files, php, directory-structure

I'm currently doing a CTF challenge and have extracted what I assume is the flag by injecting a relative path into the `$filename` parameter of a call to the PHP function

```
file_get_contents($filename)
```

that is executed by an Apache server on the target system.

I got the name of the file the flag was hidden in through a hint at some other point but I was wondering:

**Is there a file that's commonly present on a Linux system that holds information about the directory structure and files contained in these directories?**

I've tried searching through several log files in order to find references to interesting files but I've yet to find a detailed list of file names. I also do not have permission to read entire device files. I do have full control over the `$filename` parameter but from I gathered, I can only insert absolute or relative paths without wildcards in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `locate` command, which is installed on most Linux machines, gets its information from a database containing all the paths on the system. A cron job maintains this database.

There are competing implementations of `locate` and probably competing ideas on where the database should be, so you may have to dig up a few versions to find all the places where it might be hiding. (If you were on the machine already you could `locate locatedb`!)

On my Debian machine it's `/var/cache/locate/locatedb`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking about the inodes and superblock.
See: http://www.linfo.org/superblock and [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)

File systems don't have any need for a "master file" to keep track of all the files and directories contained within, per se. So, I'd say no, there is no **"file that's commonly present on a Linux system that holds information about the directory structure and files contained in these directories"**.

However, through the use of inodes and the super block, file systems do keep track of all the files and directories. But in a distributed, non-centralized fashion.